# django session user

Tags: mysql, django, pinax

How to find user from django_session?

django sets a cookie named 'sessionid' which stored in django_session table as session key.
django_session table also contains session data corresponding to each session key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/12/04/get-user-from-session-key-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to extract session dict:

```
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L86
```

In that dict you should have user id written there by auth middleware:

```
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L60
```

(Sorry for links being not links - something was breaking)

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't use `request.session` and `request.user` from within a view to get the session info and user, respectively?